# Flutter - Text form field input format as de (German) locale

Tags: flutter

I have a TextFormField I want to accept input 12.32 as 12,32 because that's how we write float numbers in German.

I tried searching for the solution could not find it. Please comment the link if you find the solution.

**EDIT**

For anyone who is facing the problem, That's how I fixed it.

https://dev.to/mohitkyadav/format-double-according-to-locale-1122

Comment: i don't understand can i know more about your question? the numbers that you wrote are the same

Comment: I am facing the same problem but cannot implement your solution. I have TextInputType.number and a Textinputformater which looks for an exception in the Numberformat.parse method. Can you provide the solution with your TextField plz?

Comment: this worked for me https://dev.to/mohitkyadav/format-double-according-to-locale-1122

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **parse** texts in a country/locale specific way, you can use the class [NumberFormat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat-class.html).